# Difference between rvm and rvm use

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

This is a simple question, but I cannot seem to find a good answer in the docs (I'm a newbie with RVM).

What is the difference between rvm use ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3 and rvm ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3?

Was trying to setup two versions of my gemsets for 2 projects (rails 3.1 and 3.0.9) and was going to do:

```
rvm gemset create proj1 proj2
rvm 1.9.2-head@proj1
gem install rails -v 3.1

rvm 1.9.2-head@proj2
gem install rails -v 3.0.9
```

and then trying to figure out whether to use

```
rvm 1.9.2-head@proj1
```

or

```
rvm use 1.9.2-head@proj1
```

to switch to that project/gemset. Hence my question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the rvm command alone is meant  to be used to run something against multiple versions of ruby/ruby gems. For example, you can specify `rvm 1.9.2,1.8.7 test.rb` and it will execute test.rb using both rubies.

In contrast, `rvm use` sets up your current shell environment to use whatever ruby you've passed. so if you `rvm use 1.9.2@proj1`, your next ruby command can simply be `ruby whatever.rb`, and rvm will pick ruby 1.9.2 using your proj1 gem set.

so, to sum it up, use `rvm 1.9.2,1.8.7 something.rb` when you want to run against multiple rubies, use `rvm use 1.9.2` when you want to set the ruby your current shell will use.

**EDIT**

This would've just looked terrible in a comment, so I'm editing instead. My output from those rvm commands looks like:

```
## RVM use will set the ruby for this shell
[Moe:~]$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /Users/nunya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
[Moe:~]$ ruby -e 'puts `rvm current`'
ruby-1.9.2-p290

## rvm without the use will execute the command with all the rubies passed, 
## but will leave the shells ruby alone.
[Moe:~]$ rvm 1.9.2,1.9.3 -e 'puts `rvm current`'
ruby-1.9.2-p290
ruby-1.9.3-preview1
[Moe:~]$ ruby -e 'puts `rvm current`'
ruby-1.9.2-p290
# with a single ruby:
[Moe:~]$ rvm 1.9.3 -e 'puts `rvm current`'
ruby-1.9.3-preview1
[Moe:~]$ rvm current
ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

Comment: makes perfect sense but when i use rvm 1.9.2@proj1 and then execute rails server or whatever, it works the same as if i were to have run rvm use 1.9.2@proj1. so i am still confused?

Comment: maybe your shell was previously set to use 1.9.2@proj1? I'm not getting that in mine.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

and just plain

```
rvm 1.9.2
```

is simply whether RVM will display information about the change from one ruby|ruby@gemset to another. The 'use' keyword just causes RVM to display the changed-to set.